# Start Ubuntu GUI from CLI

Tags: gnome, xorg, xvfb

I am having trouble starting the Ubuntu GUI from CLI. I currently have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. I ran the following command to disable the GUI to start on boot (this is a headless server).

```
systemctl set-default multi-user
```

I started an instance of Xvfb as follows:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1920x1080x24*32 -nocursor -fbdir /var/tmp &
```

Now I read online that I could run this command to start the UI:

```
DISPLAY=:1 gnome-session --session=ubuntu &
```

However the UI looks slightly odd and is definitely not the default 20.04 Ubuntu UI. For example the side doc is missing, icons are missing. My desktop is empty etc.

Commands I have tried:

```
startx
systemctl start gdm3.service
systemctl isolate graphical
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.